# Returning Obj& in C++, what happens to the temp pointer?

Tags: c++

Class

```
class Dummy
{
public:
    int x;

    Dummy(int y):x(y)
    {
    }

    ~Dummy()
    {
        std::cout<<"boom"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

Function

```
Dummy& getRef()
{
    Dummy* temp = new Dummy(5);
    return *temp;
}
```

Call

```
Dummy* get = &getRef();
std::cout<<get->x<<std::endl;
get->~Dummy();
```

My intention was to get a dynamic object instance from a function and then pass it into a pointer at main.

My question:

After calling `get->~Dummy();`, is the pointer `Dummy* temp` still alive or dangling?

I know that objects that are dynamically created won't get destroyed unless the destructor is called(even if it goes outside the scope) but i am not sure about the pointer itself.

The issue can be easily overcome by using `unique_ptr` but i want to know more about lifecycles.

Comment: You should be calling `delete get;`, not manually calling the destructor. But returning a reference to a newed object will invariably lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Oops i forget to add that part. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @juanchopanza "But returning a reference to a newed object will invariably lead to memory leaks" – no, if he `delete`s the address of the returned reference, then it won't leak. (not that it's a wise thing to do, however…)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I would bet my house on the fact that it will lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @juanchopanza why is it not a wise thing?

Comment: @CarloBrew the subtle leaks come in several forms, such as when someone does something seemingly trivial, like `Dummy obj = getRef();` A ton of things can go wrong with what looks like correct code to anyone but the original author of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that objects that are dynamically created won't get destroyed unless the destructor is called.

That isn't accurate . Destructors fire *when* an object is being destroyed unless someone has solid reason to manually fire them (and you *don't* here). They don't *instigate* that destruction. Something else does (whatever kicked off the object destruction, be it scope-exit, a `delete`, etc).

And yes, you're leaking memory. You have a `new` without a corresponding `delete`. There is the very soul of a memory leak. If you lose the manual destructor invoke and use

```
delete get;
```

your code will be sound (though odd, none-the-less).

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is just a location in memory. When your function `getRef()` exits the `temp` variable is gone, but that allocation is still present.

You can still get the address from the return variable.

```
delete get;
```

will destroy your object

If the calling code doesn't delete that object you have a memory leak.

Explicitly calling destructors is generally not wise. Some instances like scripting languages require this kinda of thing but its rare.

Comment: So when the temp goes out of scope, the pointer gets deleted?

Comment: The variable 'temp' which is pointer is gone when the function returns. But the memory you have allocated is still present. This is generally considered 'bad' although sometimes you need todo this and pass responsibility to the calling code to delete the object.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why is it not wise to explicitly call destructors?

Comment: @CarloBrew If you call the dtor manually then `delete get;` it will call the object's dtor again, and a double dtor call is undefined.

Comment: @CarloBrew `delete` will call the dtor for you.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated memory with `new`, so the memory is only released when you `delete` it (which you do not do). The destructor of the pointee object doesn't deallocate anything.

You explicitly call the destructor of the pointee object, so it is "destroyed" but not deallocated. If you then `delete` the pointer, the destructor will have been called twice, which you do not want.

Only explicitly call a destructor when you intend to use placement `new` to construct a new object in the memory it formerly occupied. After explicitly calling the destructor (`get->~Dummy()`) the pointer still points to a valid memory location, albeit without a constructed object at that location.

Answer (score 0):

What really happens in your example (though you SHOULD NOT write this kind of code):

- within getRef() (line with new Dummy(5)), allocation happens, AND constructor is called within allocated space
- until get->~Dummy() no changes are made; it seems (though here I'm not exactly 100% sure) that all the conversions from pointers to references and back are irrelevant and don't cause any constructors to be called (in any case, you shouldn't do these kind of things, at least for readability)
- when get->~Dummy() is called, it calls destructor, but doesn't deallocate underlying memory block. After this point, you can call "placement new" with your 'get' pointer, creating a different object within the same allocated space (and having the same memory address), or you can deallocate memory block (using whatever-your-library-new-uses-for-allocation), or you will have a memory leak (as PhilCK has noted).

As a rule of thumb, you SHOULD NOT call destructors explicitly for objects you've created via 'new', as it has quite special meaning (see above); use 'delete' instead ('delete' will both call destructor and deallocate underlying memory block).